# change JSSOR image Tab position

Tags: tabs, slider, position, jssor

I have 2 Question ...

1- I'm using Jssor image Tab slider.
The tab position are in top of slider. I want to change position and put tabs in button in slider. how can I change the position?

2- I want to have a slider with low size (for fast loading).
How can I short the functions in JS files( jquery and JSSOR files)

Answer (score 0):

Tab is a kind of thumbnail navigator.

You can see 'slides' container, and 'thumbnail navigator' in the 'outer container'.

```
<div id="slider2_container" ...>
    <div u="slides" ...>
        ...
    </div>
    <div u="thumbnavigator" ...>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Re 1:
You can adjust position of 'slides' container and 'thumbnail navigator' by change 'style="top: ...px; left: ...px;"'

Re 2:
You can adjust size of 'outer container' and 'slides' container by modifing 'style="... width: ...px; height: ...px;"'